# slideOut sidebar appears again

Tags: html, angular, css, css-animations

I have a sidebar that I'm sliding in/out. When I slideOut on a button press it slides to the right to hide, but reappears again when it should be hidden.

Sidebar appear on button click and it hides when you press the x icon

**CSS**

```
.pay-storage-container {
  $inner-padding: 16px;
  height: 100vh;
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 325px;
  border: 1px solid #c0c2c7;
  z-index: 1;
  //Other subclasses
}

.showSideBar {
  animation: slideIn 1s;
}

.closeSideBar {
  animation: slideOut 1s;
}

@keyframes slideIn {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateX(350px);
  }

  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translate(0);
  }
}

@keyframes slideOut {
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateX(350px);
  }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="pay-storage-container {{toggleSideBar ? 'showSideBar' : 'closeSideBar'}}">
  <div class="header-container">
    <div class="header">Pay Storage</div>
    <span class='close-icon csx-common_delete' (click)="closeSideBar()"></span>
  </div>
  <div class="pay-storage-inner">
    <div *ngIf="paymentMessage$ | async as message">
      {{ message | json }}
    </div>
    <app-equipment-summary [equipmentSummary]='equipmentSummary'></app-equipment-summary>
    <app-credit-card #creditCardForm></app-credit-card>
    <div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="footer-container">
    <button pButton type="button" label="Submit Payment" class="x-primary-green-400" [disabled]='!creditCardForm.creditCardForm.valid'
      (click)="onSubmitPayment()"></button>
  </div>
</div>
```

I'm using angular in this project and I have a variable in a .TS file that toggles the classes to change the sliding in/out.

**TS**

```
toggleSideBar = true;
.
.
.
closeSideBar() {
    this.toggleSideBar = false;
}
```

I'm very super it's a problem with the css not with the angular side, but I still added in case y'all wanted to take a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add  `animation-fill-mode: forwards;` to the `closeSideBar` class. This will ensure that the animation is not reset after it reaches 100%

```css
.pay-storage-container {
  $inner-padding: 16px;
  height: 100vh;
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 325px;
  border: 1px solid #c0c2c7;
  z-index: 1;
  //Other subclasses
}

.showSideBar {
  animation: slideIn 1s;
}

.closeSideBar {
  animation: slideOut 1s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes slideIn {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateX(350px);
  }

  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translate(0);
  }
}

@keyframes slideOut {
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateX(350px);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="pay-storage-container closeSideBar">
  <div class="header-container">
    <div class="header">Pay Storage</div>
    <span class='close-icon csx-common_delete' (click)="closeSideBar()"></span>
  </div>
  <div class="pay-storage-inner">
    <div *ngIf="paymentMessage$ | async as message">
      {{ message | json }}
    </div>
    <app-equipment-summary [equipmentSummary]='equipmentSummary'></app-equipment-summary>
    <app-credit-card #creditCardForm></app-credit-card>
    <div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="footer-container">
    <button pButton type="button" label="Submit Payment" class="x-primary-green-400" [disabled]='!creditCardForm.creditCardForm.valid'
      (click)="onSubmitPayment()"></button>
  </div>
```

Comment: You are killing it! Thanks so much. I knew it was something simple